# Getting Element Value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to solve one issue for about 2days.

Let's imagine I have this kind of Html element in my code (actually anywhere in my code)

```
<p id='el'>some values</p>
```

If I want to get the element by id I can write this kind of js code

```
getElementById('el')
```

But How can I get the value inside of `p`

Actually I'm working on Angularjs code and I tried to get the element by `id` by writing

```
angular.element('el') //but it not worked
```

Is there any good or better ways to get the element value?
Please share your ideas. Also if possible not jquery solvings.
Thank you

Comment: document.getElementById('el').innerHTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular.element uses the 'css query' syntax, so you need '#el' to select element with id 'el'.

In general you could probably use a two way binding (`<p>{{values}}</p>`) but I don't understand your situation

Comment: no no @Vally3y I know how to bind models the thing is How to get the value inside of `<p>` is there any possible ways?

Comment: As I said, `angular.element('#el')` should select the element. Then you can use the text function. `angular.element('#el').text()`